# Missing coverage for catch branch

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am starting to create an API using Node.js and Koa. I'm using Mocha/Chai for testing, but for some reason any of my `try/catch` blocks are not testing the `catch` block. For example, here is output from Coveralls.io:

```
router.get(BASE_URL, async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const companies = await queries.getAllCompanies();  
    ctx.body = {
      status: 'success',
      data: companies
    };
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = 400;     // !
    ctx.body = {          // !
      status: 'error',
      message: err.message || 'Sorry, an error has occurred.'
    };  
  }
}
```

> Branches [[0, 0], [0, 1]] missed.

I have marked the two lines with `// !` that are referred to in the code. Here is the relevant section of my `test.js` file that tests the `GET` API:

```
describe('GET /api/v1/companies', () => {
  const companies = realm.objects('Company');
  it('should return an empty list', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/api/v1/companies')
    .end((err, res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.status.should.equal(200);
      res.type.should.equal('application/json');
      res.body.status.should.eql('success');
      Object.keys(res.body.data).length.should.eql(0);
      done();
    });
  });
  it('count should be 0', (done) => {
    companies.length.should.eql(0);
    done();
  });
  it('should return 3 newly added companies', (done) => {
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Company', { id: '1', companyName: 'test company 1' });
      realm.create('Company', { id: '2', companyName: 'test company 2' });
      realm.create('Company', { id: '3', companyName: 'test company 3' });
    });

    chai.request(server)
    .get('/api/v1/companies')
    .end((err, res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.status.should.equal(200);
      res.type.should.equal('application/json');
      res.body.status.should.eql('success');
      Object.keys(res.body.data).length.should.eql(3);
      res.body.data[0].should.include.keys('id', 'companyName', 'notes', 'notesSalt');
      done();
    });
  });
  it('count should be 3', (done) => {
    companies.length.should.eql(3);
    done();
  });
});
```

What do I need to do to add coverage for the `catch` block? I have the same issue with multiple APIs, so I would definitely like to get the tests corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually an "await" statement is a wrapper around the "promise" within try-catch block. Because of this, any errors that occurred in "await" section actually occurred in wrapper try-catch block. So you cannot catch these errors like this.

But you can get error like this,

```
await queries.getAllCompanies().catch((err) => { ... })
```

Comment: When I try to catch the error in this way, I get `TypeError: queries.getAllCompanies(...).catch is not a function`

Comment: I think that the issue is that the `queries.getAllCompanies()` does not ever throw an error in the test cases, so the `catch()` block is never reached. I removed the `try/catch` block for now and handle any errors within the `getAllCompanies()` function.